# FXM External Site Not Showing Added Component

Tags: fxm

I am using `Sitecore 8.1  (rev. 160519)`. In Sitecore `FXM` experience editor I have added one placeholder and component on it and publish all these changes, but it is not reflected on External Site.

There are no errors in the FXM log files and the component is showing correctly in the FXM Experience Editor. When I try to figure out the external app post call request all was good but the component data is not present in the post call response.

There is also one capture click action which is working fine on external site and the click event is also getting captured in Sitecore Analytics. But the added component is not showing on external site.

Below is the response for the external site post call ,

```
{
    "ContactId":"17c0b00fdc2940bb9bfd9e18ebe16b1b|True",
    "SessionId":"pwes2czzeopmpwu5yxvsinv4",
    "ContactExpires":"2019-06-09T15:38:33.2587405",
    "SessionPath":"/",
    "ElementMatches": [
        {
            "Event":"click",
            "Selector":"#sampleTest8",
            "MatchType":"event",
            "Id":"{55E71BAE-B122-4368-8336-87971355D099}"
        },
        {
            "Event":"click",
            "Selector":"#myButton",
            "MatchType":"event",
            "Id":"{A3433F6F-CFE2-4642-B98F-DBFA8937B1AC}"
        },
        {
            "RenderedContent":"<form method=\"post\" action=\"/sitecore/api/ssc/Beacon/Service/beacon/trackPageVisit/?contactId=17c0b00fdc2940bb9bfd9e18ebe16b1b%7CTrue&amp;sessionId=pwes2czzeopmpwu5yxvsinv4&amp;page=http%3A%2F%2Fuatatpredesignexternalappfxm%2F&amp;referrer=&amp;rt=1497008313221\" id=\"ctl00\">\r\n<div class=\"aspNetHidden\">\r\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"/wEPDwUENTM4MQ8WAh4TVmFsaWRhdGVSZXF1ZXN0TW9kZQIBZGS4wHrFc7sgWChOhH+pjsBq5hYlqg==\"/>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n <div class=\"aspNetHidden\">\r\n\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\" id=\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\"  value=\"B82EF22B\" />\r\n</div></form>",
            "RenderedPosition":"{B8F49EBF-2542-4CB0-B3BB-63858918CE8B}",
            "Selector":"#sampleTest1> > b" ,
            "MatchType":"content",
            "Id":"{D8C7CE48-E12A-4703-A16D-C0F20D728B2F}"
        }
    ],
    "Id":null,
    "Url":null
}
```

Comment: did you publish the component that you render? I can see RenderedContent is emtpy

Comment: Yes i had publish it and also checked in web database

Comment: did you configured Language Rules ?

Comment: https://timbarreto.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/fxm8.png?w=1000

Comment: Thank you so much , as suggested by you after adding Language Rules the external site is now showing the added component.

Comment: I will transform my comment in an  answer :)

Comment: It's not working in sitecore 9.0.1. When i login to sitecore and edit external site then if i open external site then i can see component. Any idea why? I did add rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a general issue if you don't publish or you not configure Language rules.

Please look on a attached picture how to configure Language rules.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution ,now it is working fine , but just one doubt , I tried the same thing on fresh Sitecore 8.1 instance there it is working without adding language rule , but on our dev environment to work this thing , I added language rule , is this is because that on dev there are multiple languages and on fresh instance there is only one language ?

Comment: yes you are right