# FXM experience editor language not defined warning

Tags: fxm

I am having issues trying to get my content to appear on my external site ([http://fxmtesternetrafael.azurewebsites.net](http://fxmtesternetrafael.azurewebsites.net/)) using FXM. I see 200 beacon responses but the eventual MatchesElements is [] blank.

> {"ContactId":"d8ee9e3e0d6f4b67ab9b58ab013311b8|True","SessionId":"v2ln3g5enhe4zac5fmq1n3ss","ContactExpires":"2020-07-25T19:24:33.4279565","SessionPath":"/","ElementMatches":[],"Id":null,"Url":null}

I am using the experience editor within FXM and I keep getting the following warning which might the root of my issues:

> This page is in undefined. You are currently creating items in English. Change language to 'undefined'

[image]

I have tried troubleshooting wise publishing at all levels and making sure I have the right selectors but when I add the language rules advised here [FXM External Site Not Showing Added Component](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6072/fxm-external-site-not-showing-added-component) I started seeing the undefined language warning. Help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah my issue was that the Sitecore site I was using to manage FXM was behind my corporate Internet and was blocking building the appropriate response back to my external site.

When I used a Sitecore site that was exposed out to the Internet then everything works as intended.

Sigh I spent to much time on that!